# Text from user input variable not staying in div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am taking a variable from an HTML `form` element and trying to put it into a `div` to be displayed on the website whenever I click a button. However it shows up for a second then pops away.

I tried taking it out of the `document.ready()` block but that didn't work. When I put a string literal in the `$(".output").html` the same problem occurs as well. Similar questions like mine seem to be a syntax error, but I don't seem to have any I can find.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sub").on("click",function(){
    var searchstring = $("#searchfield");
    $(".output").html(searchstring.val());
  });
});
```

Here is my site on codepen: http://codepen.io/arcjackson06/pen/NNeQvJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<button>` will submit the surrounding form. You need to use:

```
<button class="..." type="button"></button>
```

Which will prevent the form from submitting when clicked.

Alternative you can prevent the default click event, with:

```
$('.sub').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".sub").on("click",function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchstring = $("#searchfield").val();
    $(".output").html(searchstring);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for any extra JavaScript.

Just give your button an attribute `type="button"` and that should take care of it.

The problem is a button's default type is submit so you are refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the form on your page is submitting every time someone clicks that search button. To prevent that you need to use [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$(".sub").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchstring = $("#searchfield");
    $(".output").html(searchstring.val());
```

Answer (score 1):

When someone is clicking on  , Its submitting the form and your page is getting reloaded.  If you donot want to submit the form

You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".sub").on("click",function( event ){
     var searchstring = $("#searchfield");
     $(".output").html(searchstring.val());
     event.preventDefault(); // This will prevent the form submission
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's refreshing the form. That's why you don't see value. See updated codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGwNJP

I added return false as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(".sub").on("click",function(e){
     var searchstring = $("#searchfield");

  $("#output").html(searchstring.val());
    return false;
    // Or e.preventDefault();



    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can add e.preventDefault(); as well.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using form it would try to do forms default action i.e. submit.

Here you need to do event.preventDefault in onclick handler.